# iOS 7.1.4 Recovery

Tags: iphone, ios

For iOS 7.1.4 or any iOS 7 version how do I access the recovery mode? I want to enter recovery mode for my new iPhone 5s. Can anybody tell me how to get in / out of recovery mode? Please post your suggestion and what I should do or a warning before entering recovery mode or if it is safe. I forgot my password (reason)

Comment: Which problem are you trying to solve by getting into recovery mode?

Comment: Recovery Mode is generally used as a last resort for restoring your iOS device if you have forgotten the passcode. Is this the case?

Comment: Yes. I forgot my password.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure to bacup your device first.
To place an iOS device in recovery mode first open iTunes, connect your dock cable to the computer, but not the I device.  Turn off your device, and then hold down the home button as you connect it to the dock cable.  Keep holding the home button until you see the 'connect to iTunes' graphic on your I device screen. iTunes will alert you that a device in recovery mode has been detected and you must restore the device.  This is a completely safe thing to do as long as you have a recent backup and there is no damage to your dock connector.